# Unable to access google sheets using api key

Tags: c#, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client, api-key

Unable to access google sheets using v4 .net client library specifically using update and append methods.

get methods works fine, i'm able to read values from the sheet.
but when i try to update or append i am getting as

`Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. [401]
Errors [
    Message[Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.] Location[ - ] Reason[unauthorized] Domain[global]
]
'`

i'm running both the code using same service initialization yet i get the error.

here is the code

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SheetsQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
    static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
    static string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";
    static String spreadsheetId = "{{SpreadSheet_ID}}";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /*
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }
        */
        // Create Google Sheets API service.
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            //HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            ApiKey = "{{API_KEY}}",
        }
        );



        // Define request parameters.

        String range = "A2:E";
        //get request / for reading
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);
        IList<IList<Object>> val = GenerateData();
        string newRange = GetRange(service);

        //append request 
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest arequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(new ValueRange() { Values = val }, spreadsheetId, newRange);

        ValueRange response = request.Execute();
        IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
        if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var row in values)
            {
                // Print columns A to E, which correspond to indices 0 to 4.
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
        }


        Console.Read();

        arequest.InsertDataOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum.INSERTROWS;
        arequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;

        /*
        *
        * Works till here
        *
        */

        var aresponse = arequest.Execute();

        Console.WriteLine("Inserted");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static IList<IList<Object>> GenerateData()
    {
        List<IList<Object>> objNewRecords = new List<IList<Object>>();

        IList<Object> obj = new List<Object>();

        obj.Add("Column - 1");
        obj.Add("Column - 2");
        obj.Add("Column - 3");
        obj.Add("Column - 4");
        obj.Add("Column - 5");
        objNewRecords.Add(obj);

        return objNewRecords;
    }

    protected static string GetRange(SheetsService service)
    {
        // Define request parameters.
        // String spreadsheetId = ;
        String range = "A:E";

        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest getRequest =
                   service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

        ValueRange getResponse = getRequest.Execute();
        IList<IList<Object>> getValues = getResponse.Values;

        int currentCount = getValues.Count() + 2;

        String newRange = "A" + currentCount + ":A";

        return newRange;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You set the scope as SpreadsheetsReadOnly, perhaps if you change it to  'Spreadsheets' it works out.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that you can write to a Google sheet with an API key but check that you have set it to full public Access not just read public Access.    If this doesn't work continue reading.

API key is used to access public data.   While you can use it to read from a public Google sheet you are not going to be able to write to it.    This is probably due to the lack of scope in authorization with api keys.

You need to use oauth2 or a service account with the proper write scope.

Comment: yeah, it seems like its not possible to write with an API key, though i haven't seen any docu' saying so.

Comment: I know you can't upload to Google drive it kinda of makes sense